# Flutter in App Purchases purchase stream doesn´t fire after buying an item

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, flutter-provider

I am currently trying to add in app purchases to my flutter app.
For implementing I used the [in_app_purchases](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) package and the google [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#0)

My Code is very similar to the codelab:
I have a Purchases class extended with a Change notifier (similar to the DashPurchases class in the code lab), that contains all of the functions to load and purchase items.

I can see my in app item and I can buy it.

[image]

After i bought it, it also says "payment successful"
[image]

So basically everything is working fine.

The problem is, that after i call the `buyNonConsumable` function, my stream that i am listening to doesn´t recognize it. So I can buy the item but can´t handle anything after i bought it. I don´t know why my listener doesn´t call the `_onPurchaseUpdate` function in that case. For clarification: I want to remove all the ads in the app after the user buys that item.

Here is my code:

```
class Purchases with ChangeNotifier {

  StoreState storeState = StoreState.notAvailable;
  late StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>> _subscription;
  List<String> alreadyBoughtproductsList = [];

  final iapConnection = IAPConnection.instance;
  final inAppProductIds = <String>{'remove_ads'};

  Purchases() {
    final purchaseUpdated = iapConnection.purchaseStream;
    _subscription =
        purchaseUpdated.listen((List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
      _onPurchaseUpdate(purchaseDetailsList);
    }, onDone: () {
      _updateStreamOnDone();
    }, onError: (Object error) {
      _updateStreamOnError(error);
    });
  }

  Future<ProductDetailsResponse> loadPurchases() async {
    final available = await iapConnection.isAvailable();
    if (!available) {
      print("not available");
      storeState = StoreState.notAvailable;
      notifyListeners();
      throw Error();
    }

    var tempList = inAppProductIds;
    tempList
        .removeWhere((element) => alreadyBoughtproductsList.contains(element));

    if (tempList.length == 0) {
      return getProductDetailsResponseFuture();
    }

    final response = await iapConnection.queryProductDetails(tempList);
    storeState = StoreState.available;
    notifyListeners();
    return response;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // this function gets called and calls the buyNonConsumable function(tested it with the debugger)
  Future<void> buy(ProductDetails productDetails) async {
    final purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: productDetails);
    switch (productDetails.id) {
      case 'remove_ads':
        await iapConnection.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
        break;
      default:
        throw ArgumentError.value(
            productDetails, '${productDetails.id} is not a known product');
    }
  }

  // this function never gets called (tested it with the debugger)
  Future<void> _onPurchaseUpdate(
      List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {
    for (var purchaseDetails in purchaseDetailsList) {
      await _handlePurchase(purchaseDetails);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> _handlePurchase(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
    if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
      switch (purchaseDetails.productID) {
        case 'remove_ads':
        // Remove ads
      }
    }

    if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
      await iapConnection.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
    }
  }

.....

}
```

In my main.dart I create the purchases provider

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _getStartThemeModeFromSharedPreferences(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) throw snapshot.error as Object;
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return MaterialApp(
              home: new Scaffold(
                body: SizedBox.expand(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Color(0xff424242),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeChanger>(
                  create: (_) => ThemeChanger(),
                ),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<Purchases>(
                    create: (_) => Purchases(), lazy: false),
              ],
              child: new MaterialAppWithTheme(),
            );
          }
        });
  }


.....
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

I debugged the code and checked the codelab, the package example and other websites for any mistakes in my code but didn´t find anything.